# Try to save new Entitiy in Database but generated ID is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have an object "Event" and an object eventDetails. Both are jpa Entities.
The Event object contains the eventDetails by a @OneToOne annotation.

My Database has lots of events. But the eventdetails of every event are null.

In my RestController I try to fill the eventdetails like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event/{eventId}/confirm", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> confirmEvent(
            @PathVariable("eventId") long eventId, 
            @RequestBody(required = true) @Valid EventDetails data) {

        EventEntity event = eventRepository.findOne(eventId);
        if (event == null || event.getStatus().equals(EventStatus.BLOCKED)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        } else {
            event.setStatus(EventStatus.BLOCKED);
            EventDetails eventDetails = new EventDetails();
            eventDetails.setSalutation(data.getSalutation());
            //... all details here
            event.setDetails(eventDetails);
            eventRepository.save(event);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }
    }
```

But I'm not able to store this details object in the database. 
In the debuger I can see that the id of data and event is null. So its not possible to store it. But I dont know why its null. Because my EventDetails-Entity has the following Getter.

```
@Override
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK")
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet it seems that you only save the event, in which case you have to have at least cascade type persist on the relation between `EventEntity` and `EventDetails` (`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`.

Comment: if i do so i get a new error, that tell me `"HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found`

Comment: try adding `sequenceName` attribute to `@SequenceGenerator`

Comment: I've added the following but with the result, that computer says no:
Sequence "EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK" not found

`@Override
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK", sequenceName="EVENT_DETAILS_SEQ_PK")
 public Long getId() {
  return super.getId();
 }`

Comment: you have to create the sequence in the DB